# Logger functionality not working by using winston

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Logger functionality is not working. I have tried it many times. I have exported the file in user as well, but its still serving errors.

```js
/* logger.js */
const winston = createLogger({
    transports: new transports.File({
        level: "error",
        filename: "error.log",
        format: format.json(),
    }),
});

const logError = (err) => {
    logger.error(err);
};

module.exports = { winston, logError }
```

Here I have imported the `logger.js` file. Logger functionality is not working. However I have used Winston. Its still serving errors. Its showing that logger is not a function. However I have used logger in logger.js file.

```js
/* user.js */
const User = require('../models/user');

//const logger=require('../logger/logger');
const { winston, logError } = require('../logger/logger');
exports.postUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(`name:${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`)
        throw new Error('this is an error on the post');
        let user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            age: parseInt(req.body.age),
            city: req.body.city,
            status: 'ACTIVE'
        })
        let savedPost = await user.save();
        console.log(`savedPost':${JSON.stringify(savedPost)}`);
        res.json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`err:${err.toString()}`)
        logger.logError(`function:controller.postUser, error:${err.toString()} -method: ${req.method}- body:${JSON.stringify(req.body)}  date:${new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString()}`)
        res.status(500).json({ message: err })
        //logger.error(`${err.status || 500} - ${err} - ${req.method}`);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined what `logger` is. Your `winston` variable should actually be named `logger` like shown below.

```
/* logger.js */
const logger = createLogger({
    transports: new transports.File({
        level: "error",
        filename: "error.log",
        format: format.json(),
    }),
});

const logError = (err) => {
    logger.error(err);
};

module.exports = { logError }
```

and inside your user.js file

`const { logError } = require('../logger/logger');`

and when logging errors, just use `logError("Error message goes here")`